# Python merger of list elements based on word count

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose, we have a list w for example,

```
w=[ 'a word', 'more words', 'word', 'word again', 'word', 'r', 'word', 'www', 'easy word easy', 'last word' ]
```

and, the word count of each elements in the above list is 2,2,1,2,1,1,1 respectively.
Now, i wish to combine it in a way such that it satisfies a condition. Each element in the newly created list should be at least of word length 3, that means, consider the next elements for combining until the desire length is reached.
Spaces will be added at every joining point. Note that the last element irrespective of its length will be merged.

thus, the list now becomes,

```
l=[ 'a word more words', 'word word again', 'word r word', 'www easy word easy', 'last word' ]
```

I tried numerous ways but getting irrelevant results. In some cases, the last item is skipped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what `Note that the last element irrespective of its length will be merged.` means?

Comment: Suppose, the last element has only 2 word count, as in the above example, it will be added up in the new list. Same applies to all the leftover elements of the list if they do not satisfy the 3 word condition.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators + generators will do the job

```
def get_words_count(words_str: str):
    return words_str.strip().count(' ') + 1


def get_words_strings_of_desired_words_count(words_strings,
                                             desired_words_count):
    unused_words_strings = iter(words_strings)
    for words_string in unused_words_strings:
        while get_words_count(words_string) < desired_words_count:
            try:
                next_words_string = next(unused_words_strings)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            words_string = ' '.join([words_string, next_words_string])
        yield words_string


desired_words_strings = list(
    get_words_strings_of_desired_words_count(words_strings=w,
                                             desired_words_count=3))
```

Also you need to check if we are getting words count correct, maybe it will be better to use regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```
w=[ 'a word', 'more words', 'word', 'word again', 'word', 'r', 'word', 'www', 'easy word easy', 'last word' ]
l = []
current = []
for e in w:
    if not current:
        current = e.split(' ')
    else:
        current.extend(e.split(' '))
    if len(current) >= 3:
        l.append(' '.join(current))
        current.clear()
if (len(current) > 0):
    l.append(' '.join(current))
print(l)
```

The last `if` statement appends the remaining words, even if it are less than three. The script will give the following output:

```
['a word more words', 'word word again', 'word r word', 'www easy word easy', 'last word']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused with conditions for the last element that you mentioned, but try this:

```
w=[ 'a word', 'more words', 'word', 'word again', 'word',
  'r', 'word', 'www', 'easy word easy', 'last word' ]

def wordcombine(arr,n):
    temp_arr=[]
    main_arr=[]
    for num in arr:
        if type(num.split(' '))==list:
            temp_arr.append(num)
        else:
            temp_arr=temp_arr+num.split(' ')
        if len(temp_arr)>=n:
            main_arr.append(' '.join(temp_arr))
            temp_arr=[]
    main_arr.append(' '.join(temp_arr))
    return main_arr

wordcombine(w,3)
['a word more words', 'word word again', 'word r word', 'www easy word easy', 
 'last word']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ignoring end case

You can use an iterator to consume the list progressively.

```
def ensure_length(length, wordslist):
    w_iter = iter(wordslist)
    try:
        while(1):
            new_string = next(w_iter)
            while len(new_string.split(' ')) < length:
                new_string += (' ' + next(w_iter))
            yield new_string
            new_string = ''
    except StopIteration:
        if new_string is not '':
            yield new_string
```

The `try, except` statement catches the StopIteration and returns the last value. Without it, the StopIteration exception will escape.

I didn't fully understand your specification for what should be done with the last string. This function may return a last item with too small a word length.

```
list(ensure_length(3, w))
```

will return:

```
['a word more words',
 'word word again',
 'word r word',
 'www easy word easy',
 'last word']
```

### Accounting for end case

You can also improve this by maintaining a word buffer to ensure that the last element in the returned list also fulfills the condition:

```
def ensure_length(length, wordslist):
    w_iter = iter(wordslist)
    buffer = list()

    def buffer_length(buffer):
        return sum(map(lambda x: len(x.split(' ')), buffer))

    def buffer_pop(buffer, w_iter):
        while buffer_length(buffer[1:]) < length:
            buffer.append(next(w_iter))
        return buffer.pop(0)

    try:
        while(1):
            new_string = buffer_pop(buffer, w_iter)
            while len(new_string.split(' ')) < length:
                new_string += (' ' + buffer_pop(buffer, w_iter))
            yield new_string
            new_string = ''

    except StopIteration:
        if len(new_string) is not 0:
            new_string += ' '
        yield new_string + ' '.join(buffer)
```

will return:

```
['a word more words',
 'word word again',
 'word r word',
 'www easy word easy last word']
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursion solution:

```
w=[ 'a word', 'more words', 'word', 'word again', 'word', 'r', 'word', 'www', 'easy word easy', 'last word'  ]

def number_of_word(sentence):
    return len(sentence.split())

def merge_sentence(lst, accu=[""]):
    if not lst:
        return accu
    if number_of_word(accu[-1]) >= 3:
        return merge_sentence(lst[1:], accu + [lst[0]])
    else:
        accu[-1] = accu[-1] + " " + lst[0] if accu[-1] else lst[0]
        return merge_sentence(lst[1:], accu)

print merge_sentence(w)
```